# Why am I unable to add new field in Django model? I am using docker container

Tags: django, docker, django-models, django-orm

I am running the Django service in a docker container. Django has a Postgres database remote access from AWS RDS, and all this is working fine. But I am adding a new field *(amount)* in Model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    model_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(MyModel2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mymodels')
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0) # this is new field
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**MyModel** table already exists in the database. *price* is new field here.
Whenever I start server and create migrations, new migrations are created 'accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py'.

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d

docker-compose exec djangoservice bash
~\ python manage.py makemigrations
~\ python manage.py migrate
```

after this process, no changes in my database table.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?  How can I add new fields in my exesting table?

Comment: If the table already exists why is an initial migration being created? Are you always creating and applying migrations in your running container and not saving the migration files to version control?

Comment: I'm not saving migration files. How can I save them?

Comment: `git add` them like any other source file (or the equivalent in whatever other source control system you're using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get reflect all changes in the local repo that occurred in the docker container's code repository, I added a volume to sync the container with the local repo.

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/home/app_dir # this volume
    command: gunicorn djangoproject.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
```

Now build and up the container;

```
docker-compose exec web bash
/app$ cd /home/app_dir
/app$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

After executing these commands you'll see all migration files will be added to local migration folders. Now commit these files to the version control repo. i.e., git commit .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider deleting this file manually,I mean 0001_initial.py.
Sometimes migration detection of django is not very effective.